# get the text of an Item recyclerView

Tags: android

I'm working in the application of Android approached to finish it but I found the problem in recyclerView, and i didn't know how to get the text of an Item of the recyclerView ? (when i click in the item)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to create a listener that gives as argument the view and the position. It dosent exist directly like for the listView. For that you can create a class like this :

```
public class RecyclerClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
  void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

public RecyclerClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildLayoutPosition(childView));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) { }

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}

}
```

Then within your activity :

```
 recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener( // and the click is handled
            new RecyclerClickListener(getActivity(), new RecyclerClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    Log.d("click item", String.valueOf(position));   
                    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.YourTextViewID);
                            Log.d("test",textView.getText().toString());                              
                    }
                }
            }));
```

Comment: wich textView you mean?

Comment: The one in the layout_item_list of your viewHolder